# Should a density plot with ggplot return the ordered frequencies of a variable with multiple level?

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I would have a question about the density plot created with `ggplot2`. When plotting the axis of a variable with multiple levels, should that axis return the ordered sequence from the level with higher down to lower frequency?

I am not sure about the representation I got here:
[image]

This is the dataset:

```
data = data.frame(cos = c(rep('5', 308), rep('3', 199), rep('0', 184), rep('2', 9)), 
           mag = c('Yes', 'No'))
```

this is the way I have tried to sort and order variable to plot on `x axis (cos)`

```
library(data.table)
data = setDT(data)[, freq := .N, by = .(cos)][order(-freq)]
```

and here the codde for the plot

```
ggplot(data) +
  geom_density(aes(x= cos, fill = mag), alpha=0.4) +
  labs(title="Density curve",x="cos", y = "mag") +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.ticks.y=element_blank(), axis.ticks.x=element_blank())
```

Shouldn't be 5 the first point on `x axis`, due to higher frequency?

Comment: You could try either adding `+ scale_x_reverse()` to your ggplot or converting "cos" to factor and relevel, conveniently with `fct_relevel` from package {forcats}.

Comment: @I_O But the plot doesn't make sense at all if `cos` is a discrete variable. Density curves by definition show an estimate of the probability density function over a _continuous_ variable. If I look at the plot above and follow the curve that peaks at "0', what does its value over the x axis at cos = "2" represent? It's just meaningless, If `cos` is discrete then surely a (normalized) bar graph is the appropriate estimate of the probability density function.

Comment: @I_O could you please make an example?

Comment: @12666727b9 I could make an example, but I simply don't understand what you are trying to show here. Could you explain it a bit more?

Comment: @Allan: I recall this way of presentation from e.g. popular live polling software, where audience response is displayed *as though* it had been polled on a continuous (rather than Likert scale). Perhaps because a smooth rolling outline appeals to audience of all kinds (incl. software customers) more than the "old style" or even dreaded barchart from school. What would Tufte say? :-)

Comment: @AllanCameron Exactly this is the explanation. What would you suggest to get a reliable representation with density plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is not a density plot at all, since the x axis is discrete. A density plot shows the estimated probability distribution function along a *continuous* variable, so with a discrete axis, the value of a "density" curve anywhere other than the peak over each discrete x axis tick is meaningless (and potentially misleading).

From the comments, what you are looking for is effectively just a bar plot, but using bell curves rather than rectangles for the "bars".

I think the best way to do this sort of niche visualization is to work out exactly what you want to plot, wrangle the data into the correct format, then draw it with simple geoms.

It will be easier to use a continuous axis and fake-label it with the discrete levels afterwards. The wrangling might look something like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data %>%
  count(cos, mag) %>%
  mutate(cos = reorder(cos, -n)) %>%
  group_by(cos, mag) %>%
  summarise(x = seq(0, 5, 0.01), 
            y = n * dnorm(x, as.numeric(cos), sd = 0.2) / 
              dnorm(as.numeric(cos), as.numeric(cos), sd = 0.2))
```

And the plotting code, if you want the "Yes" and "No" values overlaid, would be:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = mag, group = interaction(cos, mag))) +
  geom_area(position = "identity", color = "black", alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_x_continuous("cos", breaks = 1:4, labels = levels(df$cos)) +
  labs(y = "Count") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("orange", "deepskyblue4")) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 20)
```

[image]

If you instead want them stacked, you could do:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = mag, group = interaction(cos, mag))) +
  lapply(split(df, df$cos), function(x) {
  geom_area(position = "stack", color = "black", alpha = 0.5, data = x)
    })+
  scale_x_continuous("cos", breaks = 1:4, labels = levels(df$cos)) +
  labs(y = "Count") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("orange", "deepskyblue4")) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 20)
```

[image]

If you want them dodged, you would need to wrangle the data a little differently:

```r
df <- data %>%
  count(cos, mag) %>%
  mutate(cos = reorder(cos, -n)) %>%
  group_by(cos, mag) %>%
  summarise(x = seq(0, 5, 0.01), 
            y = n * dnorm(x, as.numeric(cos) + ifelse(mag == "Yes", -0.1, 0.1), 
                          sd = 0.2) / 
              dnorm(as.numeric(cos) + ifelse(mag == "Yes", -0.1, 0.1), 
                    as.numeric(cos) + ifelse(mag == "Yes", -0.1, 0.1), sd = 0.2))


ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = mag, group = interaction(cos, mag))) +
  geom_area(position = "identity", color = "black", alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_x_continuous("cos", breaks = 1:4, labels = levels(df$cos)) +
  labs(y = "Count") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("orange", "deepskyblue4")) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 20)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your clear explanation too ;) may I just ask you by any chance if you know some method to wrangle together via dplyr both parts of code (the one finishing with summarise and the other starting with ggplot), if possible? Thanks

Comment: @12666727b9 I would normally do that by simply piping the output of summarise into ggplot (and omitting `df` as the first argument to ggplot). However, in this case we need to use the correctly-ordered factor levels of `cos` as labels in the `scale_x_continuous` call, so it is better to do this in two steps.